# Missing concrete implementation of 'getter Equatable.props'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

@immutable
abstract class AuthenticationEvent extends Equatable {
  AuthenticationEvent([List props = const <dynamic>[]]);
}

class AppLaunched extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'AppLaunched';
}

class ClickedGoogleLogin extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'ClickedGoogleLogin';
}

class LoggedIn extends AuthenticationEvent {
  final User user;
  LoggedIn(this.user);
  @override
  String toString() => 'LoggedIn';
}

class PickedProfilePicture extends AuthenticationEvent {
  final File file;
  PickedProfilePicture(this.file);
  @override
  String toString() => 'PickedProfilePicture';
}

class SaveProfile extends AuthenticationEvent {
  final File profileImage;
  final int age;
  final String username;
  SaveProfile(this.profileImage, this.age, this.username);
  @override
  String toString() => 'SaveProfile';
}

class ClickedLogout extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'ClickedLogout';
}
```

this file is authenticationevent used for google sign in for my flutter app.
i am implementing BLOC pattern so [BLoc pattern image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILhvx.png)

so i ran into this error in the title can someone suggest a fix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701509/missing-concrete-implementation-getter-equatable-issue-with-props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing concrete implementation 'getter Equatable' / issue with props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701509/missing-concrete-implementation-getter-equatable-issue-with-props)